# CSS Divs not doing auto height

Tags: html, css

I have this CSS/HTML Code:

```
#container {
    width:70%;
    height:100%;
    margin:120px auto 0 auto;
    padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;
    border:solid 1px #a79494;
    border-top:solid 4px #a2cd3a;
    padding-bottom:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
}
#body {
    width:70%;
    border:solid 1px #a79494;
    display:inline;
    float:left;
}
#property-search {
    width:20%;
    border:solid 1px #a79494;
    display:inline;
    float:right;
}

<div id="container">
<div id="body">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas et enim sed tellus luctus varius. Ut nisl felis, volutpat id ornare at, placerat ut nisi. Cras auctor, nisi vitae interdum iaculis, magna nulla pretium quam, ac euismod quam ante at sapien. Cras mattis velit sed ante pretium non pulvinar metus molestie. Maecenas euismod bibendum nulla quis interdum. Proin venenatis pellentesque lorem quis condimentum. Vestibulum sapien sapien, convallis ut semper at, hendrerit in lorem. Curabitur cursus tempor felis eu varius.
<br /><br />
In id sem neque. Nam id convallis nisl. Duis sed venenatis erat. Sed blandit auctor imperdiet. Aliquam magna erat, pellentesque at fermentum eget, cursus at nunc. Pellentesque vestibulum feugiat aliquam. Proin cursus sapien non mauris laoreet posuere. Maecenas eleifend hendrerit suscipit. Suspendisse eleifend lacus vel arcu ultrices vulputate. Mauris mattis feugiat massa vel tincidunt. Proin ut mi non ipsum tristique pretium sit amet fermentum massa. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Morbi dictum iaculis nibh, at vestibulum mauris placerat sit amet. Vivamus hendrerit molestie elit, nec porta libero semper a. Nullam in tellus erat, vitae sagittis nisi. Cras interdum hendrerit magna, at accumsan urna fermentum vitae.
<br /><br />
Sed eu libero non magna egestas lacinia. Suspendisse lacinia ipsum consequat metus aliquet laoreet. Quisque in eleifend diam. Aliquam orci lacus, ultrices non adipiscing nec, sollicitudin in erat. Etiam dignissim, felis non vulputate bibendum, lectus nunc congue massa, in porta tellus sapien id augue. Etiam odio ligula, iaculis vitae faucibus nec, sodales sed nunc. Phasellus eget neque massa, viverra facilisis arcu. Ut suscipit bibendum libero, eu consectetur leo rhoncus sit amet. Sed interdum risus a dolor venenatis ullamcorper ut ut quam. Curabitur eros leo, pulvinar ac vestibulum adipiscing, tempor nec augue. Cras tincidunt blandit libero, eget sollicitudin erat tempor eu. Donec eleifend posuere lectus. Donec turpis ante, sodales in luctus eget, feugiat non sapien. Donec sagittis nunc et ipsum gravida a scelerisque odio ultricies.
</div>
<div id="property-search">
SEARCH
</div> <!-- property-search -->
</div> <!-- body -->
```

I need the body div and property-search div to be inside the container div which they are but the container div with the border is not expanding its height when the child divs inside it are larger

here is a fiddle too: http://jsfiddle.net/bfSLD/1/

Comment: Try http://jsfiddle.net/bfSLD/1/

Comment: insert `<br style="clear: both;">` after the floating, inner elements: http://jsfiddle.net/bfSLD/4/

Comment: how about the search bit on the right - i need it to be at the top in line with the body div if possible

Comment: didn see the search box, moved the <br> down. http://jsfiddle.net/bfSLD/6/

Comment: Can I just recommend that there are better alternatives to `<br style="clear: both;">`. This answer uses invalid inline styles and is a very old fix. I recommend either using the quick fix from my answer which I have since tested, or the answer from @dfsq which is a very popular technique

Answer (score 2):

You have to clear floats:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="container">...</div>
    <div id="body">...</div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bfSLD/8/

Or better solution would be to use clearfix class:

```
<div id="container" class="clearfix">
    <div id="container">...</div>
    <div id="body">...</div>
</div>
```

For example this one from HTML5 biolerplate:

```
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {content: " "; display: table;}
.clearfix:after {clear: both;}
.clearfix {*zoom: 1;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bfSLD/12/

Answer (score 1):

Add following to the container:

```
display: inline-block;
```

Comment: that looks a bit better but i need the container to be center not left aligned

Comment: Which terminates the centering margin

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/bfSLD/9/

Is this what you want to `achive`?

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the float left from #body, and setting the display to inline-block (also on #body).

Answer (score 0):

is this what your looking for?

```
#container {
width:70%;
margin:120px auto 0 auto;
padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;
border:solid 1px #a79494;
border-top:solid 4px #a2cd3a;
padding-bottom:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
position:absolute;
}
#body {
width:70%;
border:solid 1px #a79494;
display:inline;
float:left;
}
#property-search {
width:20%;
border:solid 1px #a79494;
display:inline;
float:right;
}
```